# Trouble in Asynchronous data retrieving in Firebase using Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am absolutely new to Ionic and Firebase and was trying to create a Sample Project where I am trying to query from the Firebase Database using a check on a value. To make it clear since Firebase doesn't allow a WHERE clause in the SELECT query like conditions, so was trying to learn how to deal with that.

[Here is a snapshot of my Firebase database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgTgH.jpg)

My intention is simply to display on my View whichever data has the address value of 700030 in an array as we do in AngularJS using ng-repeat.

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'firebase'])

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray){
       
 var ref = new Firebase('https://helpee-70271.firebaseio.com');
 
 $scope.result = $firebaseArray(ref);
 
 ref.orderByChild("address").on("child_added", function(data) {
    console.log("Initially :" + JSON.stringify($scope.result));
           //console.log(data.val().address);
    if(data.val().address == "700030"){
       console.log(data.val().address);
       $scope.result.push(data.val());
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.result));
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--Firebase addition start -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <!--Firebase addition end -->
    
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title text-center">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <div>
     <div ng-repeat ="results in result">
          <div>{{results.name}}</div>
       <div>{{results.phNumber}}</div>
     </div>
  </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Code snippet. The problem am getting is that while the checking and retrieving of data is being done properly but at the View am seeing that the array containing all the elements irrespective of the Address check is getting printed first followed by the values that should be printed.

[Here is the snapshot of the View and the console of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y811u.jpg)

Can anyone please help me how to correct this issue and explain me where am going wrong? Would be highly indebted as am really new to this and am willing to learn. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are filling your array twice.
First with all the data using this line:

```
$scope.result = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

And secondly you add the data you actually want in the child_added listener:

```
$scope.result.push(data.val());
```

So the simple solution is to change that first line to:

```
$scope.result = [];
```

Comment: HI Andre, thanks for the explanation. I tried what you suggested and changed in my JS the line to  '$scope.result = [ ] ; ' but now although in the console am seeing again the array getting populated with the right elements but in the View no values are getting displayed. The View is appearing as a fully blank page with only the default Ionic header. Can you please help me out?